# How to write a query in dynamo db with a conditioned expression

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query a dynamo db table for getting company id but the same table need a hash key so my query is something like this.

```
        var optsq = {
          'ConsistentRead': true,
          'AttributesToGet': ['companyid'],
          TableName : usertable,
          Key : {
            "userid" : {
              "S" : usrname
            },
            "comapnyid" :{
              "S":''
            }
          }
        };
```

My query will only work if the query has the value of company id as well but i want to get company id how can i achive this. In my node js

```
dynamodb.getItem(optsq, function(err, compdata) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log(compdata);
  }
```

Comment: What is the primary key (hash key + range key) for the table you're querying?

Comment: @Rik hash key is user id and the range key is company id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `getItem`, you should do a `query`, which allows you to specify only the `userId`.

```
var optsq  = {
    'ConsistentRead': true,
    TableName : usertable,
    KeyConditionExpression: "userid = :userid",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":userid": usrname },
    ProjectionExpression: "companyid" }
```

Comment: While using query i am getting this.` UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params``                var optsq = {
                  'ConsistentRead': true,
                  'AttributesToGet': ['companyid'],
                  TableName : usertable,
                  Key : {
                    "userid" : {
                      "S" : usrname
                    }
                  }
                };` this is the query i have excecuted

Comment: Use `KeyConditionExpression` instead of `Key`. See above.

Comment: This worked `                var optsq = {
                  'ConsistentRead': true,
                  TableName : usertable,
                  KeyConditionExpression: "userid = :user",
                  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":user":{S:usrname} }
                };` But i am afraid that this will eat more resources also using  'AttributesToGet': ['companyid'] along with KeyConditionExpression resultted ValidationException:

Comment: Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {AttributesToGet} Expression parameters: {KeyConditionExpression}

Comment: We're getting there; try using `ProjectionExpression` instead of `AttributesToGet`, see above.

Comment: if i want more than one value over here ProjectionExpression: "companyid" }